# How many different mental states of Banri are there in Golden Time?

Tags: golden-time

It is more of a list of the different mental states of Banri and the mental states he is experiencing.

So, please correct me and expand the list. I will follow this model:

- "name". When he appears. What memories he has. Whether he is a stable or temporary state of mind.

---

1. Pre-accident Banri. Shown in flashbacks. Has all the memories pre-accident, stable.
2. Post-accident (Main) Banri. The one that enrolls university and dates Koko. Has all post accident memories (including the hospital escapade). Stable during the first three quarters of the show.
3. Ghost Banri. Several scenes throughout the whole series. Only watches, cannot interact. Has all memories (since he is the incarnation of past Banri and watched main Banri all the time). "Stable", vanishes after his unresolved issue settles after Linda's confession/answer.
4. Possessed Banri. A few episodes in the mid-series. Has pre-accident memories, but is somewhat psychotic. Very unstable.
5. Tabula rasa Banri. Last quarter of the series. Is catatonic, no memories. Unstable, reverts to main Banri after a while. Sometimes shown in the transition between possessed and main Banri (do proper names have plurals? - cross posting to ELL.SE).
6. Healed Banri. Final episodes. Has pre-accident memories only. Stable, but may have gone into possessed mode offscreen during the month he spent home to retrieve the ring.
7. "Final evolution/Awakened" (sorry for the pun) Banri. Ending, after Koko's visit and the mirror epiphany. Has all memories. Probably very stable, since he is the happy ever after version...

So, did I get it right or am I missing/mistaking something?